# piping data into command line php?

Tags: php, command-line, pipe

It is possible to pipe data using unix pipes into a command-line php script? I've tried

```
$> data | php script.php
```

But the expected `data` did not show up in `$argv`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See as well: [Detect if a PHP script is being run interactively or not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11327367/367456)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As I understand it, `$argv` will show the arguments of the program, in other words:

```
php script.php arg1 arg2 arg3
```

But if you pipe data into PHP, you will have to read it from standard input. I've never tried this, but I think it's something like this:

```
$fp = readfile("php://stdin");
// read $fp as if it were a file
```

Comment: If you replace "readfile" with "file", you'll get the input as an array of lines and it won't be automatically echoed.

Answer (score 54):

PHP can read from standard input, and also provides a nice shortcut for it: [`STDIN`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php).

With it, you can use things like [`stream_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php) and others to do things like:

```
$data = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

This will just dump all the piped data into `$data`.

If you want to start processing before all data is read, or the input size is too big to fit into a variable, you can use:

```
while(!feof(STDIN)){
    $line = fgets(STDIN);
}
```

`STDIN` is just a shortcut of `$fh = fopen("php://stdin", "r");`.
The same methods can be applied to reading and writing files, and tcp streams.

Comment: The problem is if no data is piped it prompts to input data

Answer (score 20):

If your `data` is on one like, you can also use either the -F or -R flag (-F reads & executes the file following it, -R executes it literally) If you use these flags the string that has been piped in will appear in the (regular) global variable $argn

Simple example:

```
echo "hello world" | php -R 'echo str_replace("world","stackoverflow", $argn);'
```

Comment: This works and you don't need to read from stdin. I think this should be marked.

Comment: Note that `-R` will read **one line at a time**, and execute all of the code for each line.

Answer (score 4):

You can pipe data in, yes.  But it won't appear in `$argv`.  It'll go to stdin.  You can read this several ways, including `fopen('php://stdin','r')`

There are good examples [in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
stream_get_contents(fopen("php://stdin", "r"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Came upon this post looking to make a script that behaves like a shell script, executing another command for each line of the input... ex:

```
ls -ln | awk '{print $9}'
```

If you're looking to make a php script that behaves in a similar way, this worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$input = stream_get_contents(fopen("php://stdin", "r"));

$lines = explode("\n", $input);

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $command = "php next_script.php '" . $line . "'";
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to show up in `$argv`, try this:

```
echo "Whatever you want" | xargs php script.php
```

That would covert whatever goes into standard input into command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to use -r option and take the data from the stdin. Ie I use it to easily decode JSON using PHP. 
This way you don't have to create physical script file.

It goes like this:

```
docker inspect $1|php -r '$a=json_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN),true);echo str_replace(["Array",":"],["Shares","  -->  "],print_r($a[0]["HostConfig"]["Binds"],true));'
```

This piece of code will display shared folders between host & a container.
Please replace $1 by the container name or put it in a bash alias like ie *displayshares() { ... }*

Answer (score 1):

I needed to take a CSV file and convert it to a TSV file. Sure, I could import the file into Excel and then re-export it, but where's the fun in that when piping the data through a converter means I can stay in the commandline and get the job done easily!

So, my script (called `csv2tsv`) is

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
while(!feof(STDIN)){
    echo implode("\t", str_getcsv(fgets(STDIN))), PHP_EOL;
}
```

I `chmod +x csv2tsv`.

I can then run it `cat data.csv | csv2tsv > data.tsv` and I now have my data as a TSV!

OK. No error checking (is the data an actual CSV file?), etc. but the principle works well.

And of course, you can chain as many commands as you need.

If you are wanting more to expand on this idea, then how about the ability to include additional options to your command?

Simple!

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$separator = $argv[1] ?? "\t";
while(!feof(STDIN)){
    echo implode($separator, str_getcsv(fgets(STDIN))), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Now I can overwrite the default separator from being a tab to something else. A `|` maybe!

`cat data.csv | csv2tsv '|' > data.psv`

Hope this helps and allows you to see how much more you can do!

Answer (score 0):

It can be fed by the `STDIN` as well.

```
php <<< 'Hi <?php echo getenv()["USER"];?>!'
```

---

```
echo 'Hi <?php echo getenv()["USER"];?>!' | php
```

Feeding a file into the STDIN:

```
cat code.php | php
```

---

```
php <<< $(cat somecool.php)
```

---

```
php < somecool.php
```

---

However passing strings to the shell will cause issues with some Unicode characters and may cause shell related annoyances. To avoid that, use a string encoded in `base64`:

```
system("echo '$base64String' | base64 --decode | php");
```