# Detect if a PHP script is being run interactively or not

Tags: php

I have a script that is designed to be run both as a web page, and via the console.

Detecting which method was used to invoke the script seems pretty straight forward, but when the script is being run from the console, I need to know if the script is being run interactively or not (user typing commands, or input redirected from a file).

`php script.php`
versus
`php script.php < input_file`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I also needed a slightly more flexible solution than [`posix_isatty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-isatty.php) that could detect:

- Is the script being run from the terminal
- Is the script receiving data via a pipe or from a file
- Is the output being redirected to a file

After a bit of experimenting and digging around through libc headers, I came up with a very simple class that can do all of the above and more.

```
class IOMode
{
    public $stdin;
    public $stdout;
    public $stderr;

    private function getMode(&$dev, $fp)
    {
        $stat = fstat($fp);
        $mode = $stat['mode'] & 0170000; // S_IFMT

        $dev = new StdClass;

        $dev->isFifo = $mode == 0010000; // S_IFIFO
        $dev->isChr  = $mode == 0020000; // S_IFCHR
        $dev->isDir  = $mode == 0040000; // S_IFDIR
        $dev->isBlk  = $mode == 0060000; // S_IFBLK
        $dev->isReg  = $mode == 0100000; // S_IFREG
        $dev->isLnk  = $mode == 0120000; // S_IFLNK
        $dev->isSock = $mode == 0140000; // S_IFSOCK
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->getMode($this->stdin,  STDIN);
        $this->getMode($this->stdout, STDOUT);
        $this->getMode($this->stderr, STDERR);
    }
}

$io = new IOMode;
```

Some example usage, to show what it can detect.

Input:

```
$ php io.php
// Character device as input
// $io->stdin->isChr  == true

$ echo | php io.php
// Input piped from another command
// $io->stdin->isFifo == true

$ php io.php < infile
// Input from a regular file (name taken verbatim from C headers)
// $io->stdin->isReg  == true

$ mkdir test
$ php io.php < test
// Directory used as input
// $io->stdin->isDir  == true
```

Output:

```
$ php io.php
// $io->stdout->isChr  == true

$ php io.php | cat
// $io->stdout->isFifo == true

$ php io.php > outfile
// $io->stdout->isReg  == true
```

Error:

```
$ php io.php
// $io->stderr->isChr  == true

$ php io.php 2>&1 | cat
// stderr redirected to stdout AND piped to another command
// $io->stderr->isFifo == true

$ php io.php 2>error
// $io->stderr->isReg  == true
```

I've not included examples for links, sockets, or block devices, but there's no reason they shouldn't work, as the device mode masks for them are in the class.

(Not tested on Windows - mileage may vary)

Comment: Very nice, +1 - Under what circumstances will `S_IFLNK` and `S_IFSOCK` return true?

Comment: @DaveRandom: I've never actually found out (or needed them), I included them for completeness when I was getting the masks from the C headers. They're obviously related links and sockets, but when I was experimenting I couldn't get anything to trigger them.

Comment: Thank you so much. That does exactly what I want! :)

Comment: @DaveRandom: They are for symlinks (when specifically opened as a link) and UNIX sockets respectively. These should never be true for the `STD*` streams that get setup, they are for 'proper' file streams. The same goes for block devices (typically harddrives of some type).

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for your input, but it seems that under cron job (debian) it doesn't work correctly. The STDIN is seen as piped without really using script in pipe.

Comment: @LukasS this could be an artifact of how debians cron system executes the script? You'd have to check the source for that. Traditionally cron output is sent as a mail, so it could be being piped to sendmail?

Comment: @Leigh yes, I've talked to my sysadmin and it appears that crontab on Debian runs software as piped. I've made a workaround with ENV that is set in crontab and software can check if it's being ran from crontab or not.

The idea behind my php app was to receive STDOUT and STERR from Debian's software, analyze it, parse and save it in more understandable form (and send it by mail also).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've gone ahead and created a composer package for this since I couldn't find anything that would do it: https://packagist.org/packages/hexmode/io-info

Answer (score 6):

[`posix_isatty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-isatty.php)

```
if (posix_isatty(0)) {
  // STDIN is a TTY
} else {
  // STDIN is a pipe or has no associated TTY
}
```

Obviously this only works on POSIX compliant operating systems, where PHP has the `posix` extension installed. I am not aware of a Windoze equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, you can use this:

```
$b = stream_isatty(STDIN);
if ($b) {
   echo "php script.php\n";
} else {
   echo "php script.php < input_file\n";
}
```

https://php.net/function.stream-isatty