# Pass over file to read from STDIN

Tags: php, stdin

I'm trying to get my program to read from two sources from the command line.

1. A file name passed over via a command line argument (as a String)

   php myScript.php testCases.txt
2. A file via STDIN.  I'm familiar with STDIN, fread(), etc.  but it needs to accept the notation

   php myScript.php < testCases.txt

I'm having trouble with #2.  I'm not familiar with the '<' notation between myScript.php and testCases.txt.  I'm also having a really hard time finding anything about it online.  Could someone explain what the '<' is used for in this context, and how I can utilize it in my php script in order to read in the file?

Answer (score 1):

The `>` means output to the file after the `>`. I'm guessing what you want is `<`, which means use the following file as input. In order to use both, you need to do the `<input.txt` part after you put the string argument for the other file. Doing < is basically the same as copy-pasting the contents of the file into the cmd/terminal window.

Comment: You're right, thank you for noticing that!  I'll edit my post.  How do I accept that as the input within my script though?

Comment: I revised my post. You need to put the <something.txt before the arguments, I believe

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Within my php script, how does it actually know that it needs to read from < something.txt?

Comment: I re-revised the post. It's basically as if you were to copy paste the contents of the file into the cmd/terminal window

Comment: Oh wow, that makes sense.  Thanks a ton!  It's been absolutely impossible to search for this stuff.

Comment: See [this Stack Overflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19862514/4544199) for more info